# Adding markers to CanvasRenderingContext2D in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, vector, marker

I'm using d3.js and the CanvasRenderingContext2D object described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).  I'm plotting a bunch of lines on the canvas using the following commands (inside a loop)

```
g.beginPath();
g.moveTo(nx, ny);
g.lineTo(nx+= dx*scale, ny += dy*scale);
g.stroke();
```

The issues I have is I want to add arrowheads (or other marker) to the end of these lines - and it's not clear to me how (or if) I can do this if the path is created using this approach.  I see that it can be done if I create path directly, as shown in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/9nbwS/), but would prefer to use the Context2d methods above if possible.  How does one add markers to the end of each path created using Context2D?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can add a marker to the your lines.

I think a circle is the easiest way, that way we do not have to do any calculations to determine the angle.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
context.strokeStyle = "#000";
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.lineWidth = 1;


function drawLine(data) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(data[0].x, data[0].y);
  context.lineTo(data[1].x, data[1].y);
  context.stroke();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(data[1].x, data[1].y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.fill();
}

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  drawLine([{ x: 0, y: 10 + i*10 }, { x: 200, y: 10 + i*30 }]);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```